# How to identify unique IDs and the overlap of two datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, unique

I am working with two datasets (dataset1 and dataset2) that both consist of plenty customer emails.
I would like to match  identify which emails are unique in each dataset and which are "overlapping" (which are observed in both datasets). I would like to end up with 3 datasets:

- one with emails unique to dataset1
- one with emails unique to dataset2
- one with emails that are observed in both dataset1 and dataset2 (overlap)

Here's an example for reproducability:

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(email = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ))
dataset2 <- data.frame(email = c("X", "Y", "Z", "D", "E" ))
```

The result should be:

- result1 consists of email "A", "B", "C"
- result2 consists of email "X", "Y", "Z"
- result3 consists of email "D", "E"

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%in%` :

```
result1 <- subset(dataset1, !email %in% dataset2$email)
result1

#  email
#1     A
#2     B
#3     C

result2 <- subset(dataset2, !email %in% dataset1$email)
result2

#  email
#1     X
#2     Y
#3     Z

result3 <- subset(dataset1, email %in% dataset2$email)
result3

#  email
#4     D
#5     E
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setdiff` to get the difference and `intersect` for the intersection of the datasets:

```
setdiff(dataset1$email, dataset2$email)
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
setdiff(dataset2$email, dataset1$email)
#[1] "X" "Y" "Z"
intersect(dataset1$email, dataset2$email)
#[1] "D" "E"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### It's also possible to use filtering joins from tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset1 <- data.frame(email = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ))
dataset2 <- data.frame(email = c("X", "Y", "Z", "D", "E" ))



anti_join(dataset1, dataset2)


anti_join(dataset2, dataset1)


semi_join(dataset1, dataset2)
```